# ExtJs checkbox sometimes come checked and sometimes not

Tags: extjs

I have a grid that the first column is a checkbox, and I need to bring the checkbox marked, but when I load my grid sometimes the checkbox comes checked and sometimes not comes checked,
someone could help me ??

```
            var item = record.data;
            grid.store.load({
            callback: function(response){
                Ext.each(response, function(records) {
                    Ext.each(item.links, function (valor){
                        if(records.data.id == valor.id){
                          var row = records.index;
                          grid.getSelectionModel().select(row);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        form.loadRecord(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with event `beforerefresh`. Thanks for all.

```
            var item = record.data;
            grid.store.load({
            callback: function(response){
                grid.getView().on('beforerefresh', function(view) {
                    Ext.each(response, function(records) {
                        Ext.each(item.links, function (valor){
                            if(records.data.id == valor.id){
                              var row = records.index;
                              grid.getSelectionModel().select(row, true);

                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        form.loadRecord(record);
```